# How do I read and write to a file using threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-io

I'm writing an application where I need to read blocks in from a single file, each block is roughly 512 bytes. I am also needing to write blocks simultaneously.

One of the ideas I had was `BlockReader implements Runnable` and `BlockWriter implements Runnable` and `BlockManager` manages both the reader and writer.

The problem that I am seeing with most examples that I have found was locking problems and potential deadlock situations. Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: Writing non-sequentially will in any case hurt performance. I think a blocking queue solution with a single worker (writing) thread would give better performance and less headaches...

Comment: @extraneon Seems like that should have been an answer and not a comment ;)

Comment: Just for clarity - is concurrent writing a requirement or do you just want to data generating threads to dump their data when they are finished so they can get on crunching some different block?

Comment: WarmWaffles You specify concurrent writing, and my solution does not do concurrent writing :(

Comment: @extraneon the latter, the loader will obviously load the blocks into memory, the user will mess around with it and then when finished the BlockWriter will commit the block to a file and then drop the block from memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend the book [java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000RH0EPC), in this case section 5.3 (Producer-consumer pattern).

your solution could look something like:

```
BlockingQueue<Data> queue = 
    new  LinkedBlockingQueue<Data>(MAX_BLOCKS_IN_QUEUE_UNTIL_BLOCK );

for (int i=0; i < MAX_DATA_PRODUCERS; i++ ) {
   new Thread( new DataProducer( queue ) ).start();
}

new Thread(DataWriter( queue )).start
```

Obviously DataProducer and DataWriter are runnables.

```
 class DataProducer implements Runnable {
    ...
    queue.put(data); // blocks if MAX_BLOCKS_IN_QUEUE_UNTIL_BLOCK 
                     // are waiting to be written
                     // This prevents an OutOfMemoryException
    ...
 }

 class DataConsumer implements Runnable {
   ...
   try {
       while(true) {
           writeData(queue.take()); // blocks until there is a block of data
       }
   } catch (InteruptedException e) {
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array of locks e.g. 32 and use the index of the block as a hash to determine which lock to obtain.  This way you can have concurrent read/writes (most of the time) and still ensure you won't be read/writing the same block in multiple threads.

Comment: I have no doubt that would work but I really  think concurrently writing a single file with the seeks that would require is not all that efficient. I think the Producer-Consumer pattern with a single Consumer would be better but I'd love to hear another opinion.

Comment: You should achieve the same performance either way. The P-C model may be a better design chose.