# Java read huge file ( ~100GB ) efficiently

Tags: java, file-io, io, binaryfiles

I would like to read a huge binary file ( ~100GB ) efficiently in Java.  I have to process each line of it . The line processing will be in separate threads. I don't want to load the whole file into memory. Does reading in chunks work? What will be the optimum buffer size? Any formula for that?

Comment: this might be what you want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110153/java-reading-file-chunk-by-chunk

Comment: what is a *line* in a *binary file*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write to a file using threads in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701691/how-do-i-read-and-write-to-a-file-using-threads-in-java)

Comment: BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file_to_read"), "UTF8"));
    int lines = 0;
    while (reader.readLine() != null) {
     lines++;
    }
    reader.close();

Sorry can't make this code look nice but it works

Comment: is it really a binary file or a text file to process?

Comment: _I don't want to load the whole file into memory._ Don't worry, you will not be able to ;) And you will be limited by the storage reading rate here, hope you are on a SSD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a binary file, then reading in "lines" does not make a lot of sense.

If the file is really binary, then use a `BufferedInputStream` and read bytes one at a time into `byte[]`.  When you get to the byte that marks your end of "line", add the `byte[]` and the count of bytes in the line to a queue for you worker threads to process.

And repeat.

Tips:

- Use a bounded buffer in case you can read lines faster than you can process them.
- Recycle the `byte[]` objects to reduce garbage generation.

If the file is (really) text, then you could use `BufferedReader` and the `readLine()` method instead of calling `read()`.

---

The above will give you reasonable performance.  Depending on how much work has to be done to process each line, it may be good enough that there is no point optimizing the file reading.  You can check this by profiling.

If you profiling tells you that reading is the bottle-neck, then consider using NIO with `ByteBuffer` or `CharBuffer`.  It is more complicated but potentially faster than `read()` or `readLine()`.

---

> Does reading in chunks work?

BufferedReader or BufferedInputStream both read in chunks, under the covers.

> What will be the optimum buffer size?

That's probably not that important what the buffer size is. I'd make it a few KB or tens of KB.

> Any formula for that?

No there isn't a formula for an optimum buffer size.  It will depend on variables that you can't quantify.

Comment: The file is a mainframe one which has IBM encoded data. This file is converted to binary format which means data contains certain symbols like ¥€ etc. It is stored in windows folder as a txt file. So one can say it is text . sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is a very good, thorough answer with pro tips.  Thank you.  This is the same strategy that I ended up using.  Initially I tried to parallelize the process using a bunch of threads coordinated by an ExecutorService and stowing the file data inside memory-mapped buffers; it worked, and it cut the processing time down by an order of 5, but it also consumed a ton of memory, so I fell back to using a  BufferedReader.    (FWIW, I was trying to write what was basically a multi-threaded grep in Java.)

Answer (score 0):

Java 8, streaming

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("c:\myfile.txt"));
lines.forEach(l -> {
  // Do anything line by line   
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is an efficient way of reading a big file since foreach is not beiing lazy initialized.